# Callbacks between threads

Tags: python, multithreading, callback, interrupt

There is one process, which creates thread in the middle of process's work. Now we have Main thread and Thread2. Main thread does some job and it coudln't wait for an event. Thread2 - is an infinite loop, which is waiting for a signal. When signal comes, thread2 should send command (e.g. print str) to Main thread.

Is there any way to pass the command from thread2 to Main thread without making Main thread waiting? I mean something like interrupts or callbacks.

And if there comes a signal to thread2, then thread2 interrupt Main thread work and force it to do my command (print str), or thread2 send command with callback, which goes to queue and runs when its turn in queue.

Comment: If the main-thread is truly busy the whole time and doesn't pass by some mainloop-like construct, this is impossible.

Comment: What @deets says.  Threads cannot call, or callback, other threads, only signal them.  If they are not in a position to respond to the signaling, the inter-thread comms will not be possible.